# Testing interview question

Tags: testing

When is it okay to ship a product with a bug

Comment: Don't repost a question with the same title. Also, this is not a good question. If you describe an explicit scenario, it might be.

Answer (score 1):

This is just one example, but if you are shipping an update, it is okay to ship a product with a bug if:

- the bug is not a regression, and...
- the release has features and/or other bug fixes customers are waiting for